# What's the exact effect of the security cameras in First World Bank?

Tags: payday-the-heist

Does anyone know what's the exact effect of security cameras in the First World Bank mission?  We played the mission with and without destroying the cameras, and we're not sure it's making a real difference.  The [Payday's wiki](http://payday.wikia.com/wiki/First_World_Bank_-_Walkthrough) says this:

> By the time you start heading to a room with a copier you probably
>   have killed or tied up most of the bank security personnel and shoot
>   some cameras to weaken future SWAT assaults on your team a bit.

But I doubt it.  The only difference we noticed is that only two elevators' doors will open if you destroy the four cameras in the security hall.  If you don't, the four gates will open.

Comment: I noticed that the cameras in Diamond Heist seems way more effective.  When you destroy them, cops take a lot of time to find you during assaults.

Comment: This is an excellent question. I'll need to do some research on this.

Comment: Thanks!  I've already done some, but couldn't find anything interesting.  I think the best solution so far remains to ask it directly to the dev team :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the ["Common misconceptions" section of the "Tips, strategies and other information for PD:TH](https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=384184870#2162079)" guide by DorentuZ` and Tromboncino:

> ##### Destroying cameras
>
> Destroying cameras does not make the cops less aggressive nor does it reduce the number of cops on the map or make them path towards your position faster. The effects differ per map (see below), but in general they either stop or delay the spawn of certain scripted special units.

From the ["First World Bank" section of the same guide](https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=384184870#533853):

> ##### Cameras
>
> There are three distinct "sets" of cameras in this map and each set stops a different event. The first twelve cameras, the ones you see before you have entered the vault area, control the event that spawns snipers after you've emptied the vault. Destroying these cameras reduces the chance of them spawning to 45% on Overkill and above and nullifies the chances on the difficulties below.
>
> The second set are the cameras also used for overdrill (and the one in the hallway before it). Destroying these stops two elevator doors from opening and hence stops spawns from there.
>
> For the final set of cameras I quote Frankelstner:
>
> > Breaking the remaining vault area cameras disables the spawns associated with the first elevator on the right and the second elevator on the left. Breaking the cameras before the doors have opened has no effect. Because of that, depending on your luck with the initial 5 cameras, you might disable all elevator spawns while at other times breaking the final cameras has no effect whatsoever.

Answer (score 1):

The [Payday's wiki](http://payday.wikia.com/wiki/Security_Cameras) now has more information about security cameras in general (and I confirm that from my own observations):

> Destroying the cameras will "Reduce police intel" on your team, which
>   will make it harder for the police to group up and find your squad, as
>   they are forced to spread out and search for you. More often than not,
>   if you or your team is within viewing distance of a camera, they will
>   home in on you directly.